# Do I have to wait for void async functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

Imagine the following JavaScript:

```
async function f(x)
{
     var d = await NetworkRequest(x);
     d.ProcessResponse();
}

async function g()
{
    f(x);
    // Is network io completed now?

}
```

`NetworkRequest` is a genuinely async function, one that completes asynchronously. Question - by the time f() returns, can one be sure that `ProcessResponse` is done?

What if `g` is not declared as async - will that make a difference?

Comment: The same thing would happen as with all async functions, regardless of whether or not they have a return value. You'd get a Promise *now* but it will be completed *later*. Only it'd be a void Promise but a Promise nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question - by the time f() returns, can one be sure that ProcessResponse is done?

Absolutely not.

`f` is declared `async`, it returns a promise and hands control back to `g` as soon as it goes to sleep while it awaits another promise.

That is before `ProcessResponse` is even called.

> What if g is not declared as async - will that make a difference?

No

---

This can be demonstrated:

```js
const obj = {
    ProcessResponse: () => console.log("Process Response")
};

function NetworkRequest() {
    return new Promise( res => setTimeout(() => res(obj), 1000) );
}



async function f(x)
{
     console.log("f, before await");
     var f = await NetworkRequest(x);
     console.log("f, after await");
     f.ProcessResponse();
     console.log("f, after Process Response");
}

async function g()
{
    console.log("g, before f");
    f(x);
    console.log("g, after f");
}

const x = "global";
g();
```

Answer (score 4):

Async functions **appear** to be blocking, but they actually aren't. They return a promise that resolves to their return value, because they're still asynchronously executing. If you don't return anything, it'll just return a promise that doesn't resolve to anything. In `g`, you still have to `await f(x)`.

Comment: "*Async functions appear to be blocking, but they actually aren't*" I'd say it's quite the opposite but only in some cases. One thing that's *always* stressed about async functions is that they are *not* blocking and always execute "later". Only, that's not the case. Not "always", at least - they run *synchronously* until they reach an `await` or get to the return value. So, they would *appear* to be non-blocking but in some circumstances, they actually are.

Comment: Inside the async function, `await` makes things act like a blocking function. Hence, they appear to be blocking. However, javascript's event loop is still firing and external functions are concurrently running, hence the "actually aren't [blocking]" part.

Comment: But it *doesn't* block. Maybe I'm out of touch with async functions but I've *always* been told they don't block and that you shouldn't think of `await` as actually *waiting* right now until completion. They've always been explained as syntactic sugar on top of Promises. And that's how they work, too. I've never seen any explanation or suggestion that `await` actually *blocks*. If anything, I've seen a lot more talk about how `await` works similarly to `yield`. Which, again, it does.

Comment: I think this is a very semantic argument right now, but I would consider stopping the code execution of a function to wait for a promise is essentially blocking to some degree. That's essentially all I'm trying to say here.